# Java - How to find an element in a 2D Array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Here is the problem:  Given a 2D `int` Array called `data`, return `true` if any value in the Array equals given element. Otherwise return `false`. Your program should work with arbitrarily sized Arrays in either dimension, including ragged (or irregular) arrays. For example:

`int[][] table = new int[][] { {5, 2, 8, 5, 61}, {3, 9, 6}, {10, 42, 53, 45}};`

`searchTable(table, 45) returns true`

`searchTable(table, 100) returns false`

Caveats:

> Cannot use any kind of loops, method cannot be static, cannot use class instance variables.

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean searchTable(int[][] data, int element){
    boolean result = false;
    int a = searchRow(data[data.length-1], data.length -1);
    int b = searchCol(data[a], data.length -1);
    if (data[a][b] == element)
        result = true;
    else
        result = false;
    return result;
}

public int searchRow(int [] row, int index)
{ 
    if (row.length != 0)
        return index;
    else
    {
        return searchRow(row, index + 1);
    }
}

public int searchCol(int [] col, int index) 
{
    if (col.length != 0 )
        return index;
    else
    {
        return searchCol(col, index + 1);
    }
 }
```

My output is `false` for everything.

Comment: Why are you using so many if-else just use for loop to iterate the array and take the decision

Comment: well in searchRow and searchCol you should be looking at a specific row _and_ col right. You should state them in these functions

Comment: If you can write a recursive function to search a 1-D array, then you can solve your problem by writing it twice, because a 2-D array is really just a 1-D array whose elements are 1-D arrays.

Comment: By the way, this is a horrible use of recursion, and one you would never use in real life.  Professors seem to think recursion is cool, or something.

Comment: Ajb, that's what I'm trying to do with my helper methods, but I can't figure out the algorithm. Yes, I know this is counter-intuitive, and would never do this in real-life as well.

Comment: @user3377368 Start by writing a recursive search function that takes an `int[]` (a **one**-dimensional array) and a value, and returns a **boolean**, and returns `true` if the value is in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that solves the problem recursively,

```
public boolean searchTable(int[][] data, int element) {
    return searchTable(data, element, 0);
}

private boolean searchTable(int[][] data, int element, int p) {
    if (p < 0 || p > data.length) {
        return false;
    }
    int[] row = getRow(data, p);
    if (searchRow(row, element, 0)) {
        return true;
    }
    return searchTable(data, element, 1 + p);
}

private boolean searchRow(int[] data, int element, int p) {
    if (data == null || p >= data.length) {
        return false;
    }
    if (data[p] == element) {
        return true;
    }
    return searchRow(data, element, 1 + p);
}

public int[] getRow(int[][] in, int x) {
    if (in == null || x >= in.length) {
        return null;
    }
    return in[x];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // I named the class Question.
    Question question = new Question();
    int[][] table = new int[][] { { 5, 2, 8, 5, 61 }, { 3, 9, 6 },
            { 10, 42, 53, 45 } };
    System.out.println(question.searchTable(table, 45));
    System.out.println(question.searchTable(table, 100));
}
```

Output is

```
true
false
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for your help. I was about to drop out and reenlist in the Army if I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that will return the result :

```
public class RecursiveSearch{

    int rowCount = 0;
    int columnCount = 0;
    boolean result = false;

    public boolean searchTable(int[][] data, int element){

        if(data[rowCount].length==columnCount)
        {
            rowCount++;
            columnCount=0;
        }

        if(data.length > rowCount)
        {
            if(data[rowCount][columnCount] == element)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                columnCount++;
                searchTable(data, element);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] table = new int[][] { {5, 2, 8, 5, 61}, {3, 9, 6}, {10, 42, 53, 45}};
        System.out.println(new RecursiveSearch().searchTable(table, 45));
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem I see with your code, and I know it works fine, is that you're using class instance variables. I'm sorry I should have added that to the caveats, but part of the problem is you can't use class variables.

Comment: And yes the method can't be static which just means you have to make an instance of the class in the main method to access the search method.

Comment: Caveats::'Cannot use any kind of loops, method cannot be static'.Now answer contain no more static method. @user3377368 you dont specify that instance variable can't be use

Comment: I know I forgot to specify that in the caveats, and I apologize for that.

Comment: its ohk dear @user3377368